# If zero and first conditional

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

> If you are well-organised, you (manage OR will manage) your time.

Everyone in my test was saying "will manage" is the correct answer, but the way I understand it is this sentence is talking about a general truth in the present, or it's just explaining the former sentence.

If it were worded "If you become organised" I think the answer would be "will manage" then.

What is the correct answer?

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question is, but I agree with you that "manage" would be the right word for exactly the reason you put, it is describing a general truth

Comment: @katatahito thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on context I think.

Discussing a general truth this one is correct

> If you are well-organised, you manage your time.

However, perhaps someone is not always well organised, and you are talking about an upcoming task that might be time critical, you might say to them

> If you are well-organised [in this task], you will [be able to] manage your time [effectively].

Comment: +1 Exactly. But even if somebody is always well-organized, you can still say ***will*** *manage* with respect to something in the future. (*If you are well-organized, you **will** manage your time next week.*) Perhaps it's something said by a manager to a team of people in a meeting.