# Manage or will manage

Tags: conditional-constructions, exam-questions

In exam (Egyptian GSEC English exam)

If you are a well-organized person, you (manage/will manage)

This question was in my exam, I already answered it "will manage", I want to know the difference between these two answers in this sentence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If zero and first conditional](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214499/if-zero-and-first-conditional)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need answer to an "if" question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214414/need-answer-to-an-if-question)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether the task is already being worked on or not.

It's not entirely clear from the above, since the tense is not specified.

I will give an example of either case:

Writing on a cover letter in a job application (i.e. the managing is in the future):

> I am a well-organized person, who **will manage** all the tasks.

Writing a self appraisal for a job you're in (i.e. the managing is ongoing/current):

> I am a well-organised person, who **manages** the tasks.

Therefore, I think both would be correct, depending on the context of the sentence. Although, I believe that "will manage" is more likely to be the correct answer, since it feels more like the sentence is future tense.